# React & Fuse js with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fuse.js

I have this error message when using Typescript with Fuse.js

> TS2345: Argument of type '{ keys: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FuseOptions<{ 'ISBN': string; 'title': string; 'author': string; }>'. Types of property 'keys' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '("title" | "ISBN" | "author")[] | { name: "title" | "ISBN" | "author"; weight: number; }[]'.

Here is the code:

```
let books = [{
        'ISBN': 'A',
        'title': "Old Man's War",
        'author': 'John Scalzi'
    },
    {
        'ISBN': 'B',
        'title': 'The Lock Artist',
        'author': 'Steve Hamilton'
    }
]

let options = {
    keys: 'title'
}
let fuse = new Fuse(books, options)

let filterResult = fuse.search('old')
```

The error is when hovering over options in `let fuse = new Fuse(books, options)`

Answer (score 6):

This just tripped me up for a bit too.

The compiler moves in order from top to bottom, so by the time it's looked at `options`, it's inferred it's a `string[]`, which isn't compatible with the `keyof` of your book type. So add a type annotation to your declaration of options.

Also, the `keys` should be  an array of keys.

Final result:

```
type Book = { ISBN:string; title: string; author: string; };

let options: Fuse.FuseOptions<Book>  = {
    keys: ['title'],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a better idea to provide your type to your `Fuse` instance through a generic parameter with its constructor.

So in this case, something like this would properly type all `Fuse` configuration and methods, not just your `options` object:

```
type Book = { ISBN: string; title: string; author: string; };

const fuse = new Fuse<Book>(books, { keys: ['title'] });

// filterResult is of type Fuse.FuseResult<Book>[]
const filterResult = fuse.search('old');

// or, if you want result of type Book[] 
const books = filterResult.map(({ item }) => item);
```